# css: why does my background images jump when hovering?

Tags: html, css

I would have supposed that if I give each item a fixed size and hide the underline with some margin, and then I take that margin away, it should work without issues. But it still seems to hop whenever I hover it. Please help me understand why.

https://jsfiddle.net/z5bmatr6/3/ this is what I got so far:

```css
.menu-container {
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu-item {
  background-image: url('../img/menu/main_menu.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 47px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.menu-item:hover,
.selected {
  height: 67px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.menu-about {
  background-position: 0 -80px;
  width: 133px;
}
.menu-projects {
  background-position: 0 -147px;
  width: 169px;
}
.menu-now {
  background-position: 0 -212px;
  width: 93px;
}
.menu-contact {
  background-position: 0 -275px;
  width: 164px;
}
/* About & CV */

.about-menu-container {
  width: 250px;
}
.about-menu-container .menu-item {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/qqEVD6u.png);
  background-size: 352px;
}
.menu-cv {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  width: 350px;
  /*  height: 54px;
  margin-bottom:10px;*/
}
.menu-text {
  background-position: 0 -95px;
  width: 185px;
  /*height: 42px;*/
}
```

```html
<article style="overflow-y: scroll;" class="menu-container about-menu-container">
  <h1><a class="menu-item menu-cv" href='cv.html'></a></h1>
  <h1><a class="menu-item menu-text" href='texts.html'></a></h1>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the vertical margins on the `.menu-item` element [are collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) with the default margin on the parent `h1` element. Remove the default margin from the `h1` element in order to prevent the margins from collapsing on each other (you can replace the margin with padding).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/x93owp7n/)

```
.menu-container h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) clearly outlines the rules for when margins collapse and adjoin to form a single margin. Since margins between floated boxes do not collapse, you could also float the parent `h1` element (in doing so, you don't need to remove the default margin).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ku19h5g9/)

```
.menu-container h1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Additionally, margins of `inline-block` boxes do not collapse either. Likewise, you could change the `display` of the wrapper `h1` element to `inline-block` for the same results:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ojru6kzc/)

```
.menu-container h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

As a side note, I gave the floated and `inline-block` elements a width of `100%` because `h1` elements are block level by default and they have a width of `100%`. You may want to remove/change this according to your desired results.

Comment: great answer. Thanks a lot for taking the time